# What is represent by the constant D of a vector equation of a plane

Tags: vector-spaces

We know that $r•\hat{n}=d$
,where d is the perpendicular distance from the origin

I am curious what does the D constant  of $r•n=D$ represents, is it the z-intercept or meaningless

*noted that
r is a vector that pass through a plane

n is a vector normal to the plane

$\hat{n}$ is the unit vector of n and is given by $\hat{n}=\dfrac{n}{|n|}$

d is the perpendicular distance from the origin

D is given by $D=|n|d$

Comment: Please [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4343445/edit) the question and explain what each of $•, r, \hat n, d, n, D$ (and now $\lambda$) are supposed to mean, since it's hard to understand what the question is actually asking.

Comment: @PckTsp That's just rewriting $\,r \cdot \hat n = d \iff r \cdot \underbrace{n}_{=\, \lambda\, \hat n} = \underbrace{D}_{=\, \lambda\, d}\,$. You already know what $d$ and $\lambda = |n|$ mean, and $D$ is simply their product.

Comment: "*the d here is the y-intercept of the equation*" $\;-\;$ No, it is not. By definition of the dot product, $d$ is the projection of $r$ onto the unit vector $\hat n$. That's the same as saying that $d$ is the distance from the origin to the line perpendicular to the unit vector $\hat n$ on which point $r$ lies. It works the same in 3D if you replace "perpendicular line" with "perpendicular plane".

Comment: "*D=ax+by, so isnt that D is just y -intercept*" $\;-\;$ No, the y-intercept would be $D/b\,$. When you write the 2D line as $ax+by=D$ you can multiply the equation by any non-zero constant and you get a different equation, but which represents the same line. So it's pointless to try to assign any meaning to $a,b,D$ in the general equation, because they are not uniquely determined. However, if you normalize the equation you'll always get that $D / \sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ is the distance from the origin to the line, which is $D / \lambda = d$.

Comment: Wow,brilliant.i think i had understood the concept ,thanks guys.